Office Script: Read Table 1, Process and Insert into Table2
Need some help.
I have an Excel workbook with 2 worksheets, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
In "Sheet1", there is an Excel table named “Table1”  with column “Server”, “Health”, “Error”, “PrevHealth”, “PrevError”.
The “Server” column keeps the values of server name. “Health” column keeps today’s  health status with values like “Critical”, “Normal”, “Warning”.
“PrevHealth” column keeps the previous day’s health status with values like “Critical”, “Normal”, “Warning”.
The “Error” column keeps the today’s error message of the server when the “Health” value is  “Warning” or “Critical”.
The “PrevError” column keeps the previous day’s error message when the “PrevHealth” value is “Warning” or “Critical”.
In "Sheet2", there is a blank Excel table named "Table2" with columns "Server", "LastHealth”, “LastError",
Please write an Office Script that could support Excel Automate. This script should loop through "Table1" in "Sheet1".
When in the loop,
(i) if the cell in column "Health" has value of "Critical",
insert the current row’s “Server” , “Health”, “Error” into a new row as “Server”, “LastHealth”, “LastError” of Table2 of Sheet2.
(ii)    If the cell in column “Health” is not “Critical”, but the value of “PrevHealth” is “Critical”,
Insert the current row’s “Server”, “PrevHealth”, “PrevError” into a new row as as “Server”, “LastHealth”, “LastError” of Table2 of Sheet2.
(iii)    If both the value of “Health” and “PrevHealth” is not “Critical”, skip it .
and process next row
I did some check, and tried the following code. But I encountered error as "Line 25: Table addRow: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) { 
// Get the worksheets 
const sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1"); 
const sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
// Get the tables
const table1 = sheet1.getTable("Table1");
const table2 = sheet2.getTable("Table2");

// Get the data range from Table1
const dataRange = table1.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();

// Loop through each row in Table1
for (const row of dataRange.getValues()) {
    const server = row[0]; // Server column
    const health = row[1]; // Health column
    const error = row[2]; // Error column
    const prevHealth = row[3]; // PrevHealth column
    const prevError = row[4]; // PrevError column

    // Check conditions
    if (health === "Critical") {
        // Insert a new row in Table2 with Server, Health, Error
        table2.addRow([server, health, error]);
    } else if (prevHealth === "Critical") {
        // Insert a new row in Table2 with Server, PrevHealth, PrevError
        table2.addRow([server, prevHealth, prevError]);
    }
    // Otherwise, skip the row
}



Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example


Collect all data and insert into the table all at once

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the worksheets 
    const sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    const sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    // Get the tables
    const table1 = sheet1.getTable("Table1");
    const table2 = sheet2.getTable("Table2");
    // Get the data range from Table1
    const dataRange = table1.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let dataVals:(string|number|boolean)[][] = [];
    // Loop through each row in Table1
    for (const row of dataRange.getValues()) {
        const server = row[0]; // Server column
        const health = row[1]; // Health column
        const error = row[2]; // Error column
        const prevHealth = row[3]; // PrevHealth column
        const prevError = row[4]; // PrevError column
        // Check conditions
        if (health === "Critical") {
            // Insert a new row in Table2 with Server, Health, Error
            dataVals.push([server, health, error]);
        } else if (prevHealth === "Critical") {
            // Insert a new row in Table2 with Server, PrevHealth, PrevError
            dataVals.push([server, prevHealth, prevError]);
        }
        // Otherwise, skip the row
    }
    if(dataVals){
        if(table2){
            table2.addRows(-1,dataVals);
            }
    }
}


Hi Taller, Thanks very much for your prompt answer again. By the way, when using "for (const row of dataRange.getValues()) ..." loop, could the row number be retrieved as well? Because there could be Comments (added by using the Excel "New Comment" option) in the cell of   "Health" and "PrevHealth" column of Table1. I want to retrieve the "Author Name" and "Comment Content" and insert into the Table2 as well . Meanings that the Table2 now will have 2 more columns namely "LastAuthorName" and "LastComment" to receive additional details. Thank you again.

What should I do when someone answers my question?
What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
